# Eclipse quick fix hover

Tags: eclipse

When using Eclipse, I sometimes forget to import something. I hover over the error and click "import".
Since a few days ago, this quick fix menu, disappears when I move my mouse. I first need to press **F2** for the quick fix menu to stay on the screen. I'm using the newest version of Eclipse Java 2019-09. I only experience this issue on my pc, when I use my laptop, there's no issue.

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this dialog from disappearing? I've tried looking it up but there's just nothing on the web about it...

Thanks in advance!